# Problems displaying TimeStamp in CSV

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have a CSV file download in my page. One of the fields in my CV file is timestamp.  When I open the file using MS Excel, the timestamp field is displayed like this

```
26:26.0
```

When I click on the cell, correct format is displayed in the 'fx' field in Excel. [image: This is displayed]

What should I do in order to display the correct format in the cell?? I am getting correct format when I open the CSV file using WordPad.

Comment: Not Java and not programming related. Use a proper editor to find out what's in the file. Consider converting it into XLS format, as with CSV it's locale settings dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Format Cells/Number/Custom and type `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: And when you open the csv the next time, the problem will return?

Comment: when I create other CSV, problem comes again??

Comment: Yes, Excel behaviour on reading .csv files depends on your current default data format settings. See more in: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx

Comment: Also worth mentioning when dealing with .csv files and Excel is to check your regional settings. If you match them to the .csv format you may solve your problems. http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/change-country-region-setting#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Does coding in Java help?

Comment: @JavaBeginner I don't know. I've never used Java. Maybe someone else with Java experience can answer you.